# Instagram scope parameter doesnt work

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

i have instagram follow/unfollow script, i wantto use that script to another domain, but when i take new client id the is not work, give me only basic permission.

https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=new id&redirect_uri=new callback&scope=likes+comments+relationships&response_type=code

anyone can help me?

ps:sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 3):

Instagram changed the terms for using POST and DELETE requests last week. You'll have to request access for your application. You can read more at the links below.

http://developers.instagram.com/post/116410697261/publishing-guidelines-and-signed-requests

[https://www.facebook.com/help/instagram/contact/185819881608116#*=*](https://www.facebook.com/help/instagram/contact/185819881608116#_=_)

**UPDATE**:
After Nov 2015 Documentation of instagram has been changed & now you can see **Review** article here :
https://www.instagram.com/developer/review/

Comment: hey, thanks how i can get request for Relationships and likes?

Comment: Follow the second link and you'll be able so make a request at the bottom of the page. But, they will only allow business related apps and not consumer facing apps.